# How do I trigger an event when a static mesh(sphere ball) overlaps a box trigger?

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Hi I am trying to simulate a football scenario. I have created a box trigger and a sphere as well as a third person character. I want a situation where the third person character kicks the red button over the trigger box which then triggers an event; let's say "print string"
[image: this is what my map looks like]

[image]

Comment: Might be better to ask this on AnswerHub instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your "Cast to Sphere_Blueprint" to the BeginOverlap Event, and you also need to enable the "Generate Overlap Events" on both your Sphere_Blueprint and Trigger Box. Provided that you do this, the event should fire when the components overlap.

[image: Advanced_Tutorial]